# Finding the volume bound by the curves $y = 0 $ and $y = \sqrt x$ and $\space x = 4$ about $x = 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, cross-sections

[image]this is the picture I came up with. So I am revolving around the y-axis. Therefore, I should be using the function $x = y^2$ since that is the cross-section. Moreover, I will be integrating from $0 to 2$. So, I have the integration $\int_{0}^{2}\pi y^4 = {\pi \over 5}32$. However, when I tried this online, the website got $128\pi\over 5$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sorry, it's volume.

Comment: You're calculating 'the volume under the curve' so to speak, but you have to find the 'volume above the curve'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\pi r^2 h - \frac{32\pi}{5}=\pi 4^2 \cdot (2) - \frac{32\pi}{5}=\frac{128\pi}{5}$$

Use the volume of the cylinder subtract the region that you found.

Comment: Ah ok. But if I were to revolve it around the x-axis, my answer would be $8\pi$ right?

Comment: Yes for the corrected answer.